# Onsenui;[ng:areq] Argument 'AppController' is not a function, got undefined in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

I am developing a hybrid app using Onsenui and cordova.i got this error in while loading in controller `ons-page`.
I have referred many stackoverflow questions related to this issue,but didn't get a solution

> "Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'AppController' is not a function, got
>   undefined

**Scripts**

```
<script src="js/cordova.js"></script>
<script src="lib/onsen/js/onsenui_all.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

**Html content**

```
<ons-template id="home.html" >
    <ons-navigator var="myNavigator">
        <ons-page ng-controller="AppController">
        ##contents goes here
        </ons-page>
    </ons-navigator>
</ons-template>
```

**app.js**

```
(function(){
  'use strict';
  var module = angular.module('app', ['onsen']);

module.controller('Appcontroller', function() {
 alert("inside controller");

});
})();
```

Comment: You are missing to bootstrap please add ng-app attribute to your first element  <ons-navigator var="myNavigator" ng-app='app'>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing to bootstrap your app please add ng-app attribute to your first element

```
   <ons-template id="home.html">
        <ons-navigator var="myNavigator" ng-app="app">
            <ons-page ng-controller="AppController">
            ##contents goes here
            </ons-page>
        </ons-navigator>
    </ons-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have almost same problem, but the ng-app attribute didn´t help me.
when i´m using a sample from onsenui everything is working quite good, but in my 
project, i have to load the js files dynamically and synchronously 
and then ons.bootstrap(); give me the same error 
"'AppController' is not a function, got undefined"

If same js libs in same order are declared in html doc with script tags everything is working good.

I´ve found that if the scripts are loading through normal script tags and then i´m waiting till html document is fully loaded and then call ons.bootstrap() through developer tools i got same error.

So the question is how to initlaize onsen ui after document is loaded?
Hope someone can help, I´m not very familiar with angularJS/OnsenUi... first project

**Edit:**

I have create 2 samples to demonstrate my problem.

1. working like onsenui samples.
   `jbBgmd` http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbBgmd
2. not working like in my case.
   `BoWXdP` http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BoWXdP

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: thanks, i will ask it separately, i thought that this is the nearby same problem